# Can I rearrange $ab=cd$ to get $a-c$?

Tags: calculus

Or to use the variables I'm working with, can I rearrange $P_1D_1^2=P_2D_2^2$ to find $P_1-P_2$?

I got as far as dividing both sides by $D_2^2$ to give $P_1(\frac{D_1^2}{D_2^2})=P_2$ but then got pretty lost. Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Suppose $D_1=1$ and $D_2=2$.  Then the equation you are working with reads
$$P_1 = 4 P_2$$

You can't conclude anything about $P_1 - P_2$ from that information.  For example, $(P_1, P_2)$ could be $(4,1)$, in which case $P_1 - P_2 = 3$; but alternatively $(P_1, P_2)$ could be $(8,2)$, in which case $P_1 - P_2 = 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $D_1^2$ and $D_2^2$ are constants, we can use your rearrangement to get \begin{equation*} P_1-P_2 = P_1-P_1 \left(\frac{D_1^2}{D_2^2}  \right) =P_1 \left(1-\frac{D_1^2}{D_2^2} \right) \end{equation*}
So now you can see that the result actually depends on $P_1$ (or $P_2$) itself, as the second factor is a constant. You can't go much further than that - in specific, you cannot get a term solely with $D_1$ and $D_2$, as that term would then be constant but our term is not.